# Table - equation inside a multirow

Tags: tables, equations, multirow

I would like to introduce  3 labelled equations inside a table. One of the equations goes inside a multirow. It should look like this:

[image]

I tried the following code and I get an error. When the equation  inside the multirow is deleted and, instead, a text (xxx) is written, the error disappears.

Do you have an idea, how I can solve it? Thank you in advance.

```
    \RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass{DissOnlineLatex}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{example}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
        \hline
        \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} &\textbf{c} & {\textbf{d}} & {\textbf{e}}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        1 & blabla & aaa & \multirow{2}{*}{x} & \begin{equation} m  = \frac{n}{z} \label{eq:bla2} \end{equation} \\
        \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}\\        
        2 & bloblo & bbb & & \begin{equation} m2  = \frac{n2}{z2} \label{eq:bla3} \end{equation} \\
        \hline                          
    \end{tabulary}
\end{center}
\label{table:blabla}
\end{table}
\end{document}

% x -->  a  = \frac{b}{c} \label{eq:bla1} \end{equation}
```

Comment: could you please make it a compilable MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for what you like to obtain the `tabulary` table environment is not good choice ... try with `tabularx` instead:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{example}
\label{table:blabla}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|C|C|}
        \hline
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} &\textbf{c} & {\textbf{d}} & {\textbf{e}}\\
        \hline
        \hline
1 & blabla & aaa &
    \multirow{6.5}{=}{\begin{equation}
                    a = \frac{b}{c} \label{eq:bla2}
                    \end{equation}}
                    &   \begin{equation}
                        m  = \frac{n}{z} \label{eq:bla2}
                        \end{equation} \\
        \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
2 & bloblo & bbb &  & \begin{equation}
                        m2  = \frac{n2}{z2} \label{eq:bla2} \end{equation} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
or maybe you will more prefer the following table looks:

[image]

for above images are made two changes in above mwe:

- after `\begin{table}` is added line `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`
- number of spanned lines in `multirow` is reduced: `\multirow{4}{=}{ .... }`

**note:**

- in question always provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclasss...` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem. with this you will help all who would be willing help you. it is not fun to reconstruct missing part of your code knowing that it already exist at you ...
- many time the source of problems are in used document packages, your defined commands (if existes) and similar
- newer add `\\` after ˙\hline`or`\cline`. it cause spurious vertical space in table
- displayed equations in table had to be paragraph style cells (like `p{...}˙ or`X`from`tabularx`), which should have enough with to place equation in it.
- for `multirow` in case that it contain displayed equation, you should prescribe ith width or use option `=` if the column, where is `multirow` cell has defined width.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zarko!
However, I do not understand what you mean with: to complete my mwe please first extend your code sniped to complete small document!

---------

I have problems compiling your code, I get the following error: "missing # inserted in alignment preamble". I already have \usepackage{tabularx}. Maybe it has todo with your comment.

Comment: @CRH, please add to your code fragment document preamble and other missed parts, that it can be compiled as it is. such document we call mwe (minimal working example). see comment below your question.

Comment: I added the whole code in my question above. Now it should be compilable).

Comment: @CRH, thank you very much. Now i complete my code (since i now know preamble of your document).

Comment: I didn't know the preamble was so important. Actually instead of article I have the following. I'm gonna change it in the question right now.

\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass{DissOnlineLatex}

Comment: @CRH, i add some explanation to answer. and, yes, to provide of mwe is very important. read added explanation.

Comment: @albert, thank you, the firs should be `tabulary`, of course. corrected.

Comment: @albert. now it is really it. thank you for pointing me on this spelling error.

Comment: @ Zarko. It works very well. Thank you very much for your support and your time.  It was very helpful. Have a nice day.